# Rendering HTML page Go

Tags: go, templates

I have very simple web server. I am trying to render the html file and using some templates. However, when I visit localhost:8080, I get nothing. Even source code page is empty. It does not load nor give error.

```
func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", handlers.HomePage)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I have this function:

```
 func HomePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ParseHTML("home.page.tmpl", w)
 }

func ParseHTML(s string, w http.ResponseWriter) {

files := []string{
    "./ui/html/base.layout.tmpl",
    "./ui/html/home.page.tmpl"}

ts, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
    return
}

err = ts.Execute(w, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
}

}
```

and finally, .tmpl files.

./ui/html/base.layout.tmpl

```
{{define "base"}}
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>{{template "title" .}} - Snippetbox</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1><a href='/'>Snippetbox</a></h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href='/'>Home</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
        {{template "main" .}} </main>
</body>

</html>

{{end}}
```

./ui/html/home.page.tmpl

```
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "title"}}Home{{end}}
{{define "main"}}
<h2>Latest Snippets</h2>
<p>There's nothing to see here yet!</p> {{end}}
```

Comment: `ts` is the template named `base.layout`.  That template is empty.  Reverse the order of the `files` elements so that `ts` is the template `home.page`.  See [the html.ParseFiles documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#ParseFiles) for info on how the function names and returns templates.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but how come base.layout is empty. This is where I define my template. What do you mean its empty?

Comment: The template named `base.layout` is everything in the file ./ui/html/base.layout.tmpl outside of a {{define}}/{{end}}.  There is nothing but whitespace outside of the {{define}}/{{end}}.  Swap the order of the files to render the template named `home.page`.  That template has the contents `{{template  "base" .}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes a lot of sense!